# I am trying to install IBM Control Desk

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to install IBM Control Desk but when I open launchpad and click on install components, it shows a pop up error occured see the log file. Any solutions ?

```
!SESSION 2019-05-16 03:01:17.716 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.fullversion=JRE 1.7.0 IBM J9 2.6 Windows Server 2016 amd64-64 Compressed References 20170718_357001 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - R26_Java726_SR10_20170718_1208_B357001
JIT  - r11_20170718_357001
GC   - R26_Java726_SR10_20170718_1208_B357001_CMPRSS
J9CL - 20170718_357001
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en
Framework arguments:  -toolId install -accessRights admin input @osgi.install.area\install.xml -input @osgi.install.area\install_db2_was_prod.xml
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -toolId install -accessRights admin input @osgi.install.area\install.xml -input @osgi.install.area\install_db2_was_prod.xml

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-05-16 03:01:18.231
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:77)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:516)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:539)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:512)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:709)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:192)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:56)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:629)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.enter code herelauncher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
```

Comment: Well what does it say in the log file it told you to look at?

Comment: i have posted the log file below

Comment: i have edited the question and waiting for response